# Existence of a homomorphism between groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let A,B,C,D be groups (not necessarily finite), if there are homomorphisms from A to B, A to C and B to D. Is there a homomorphism from C to D?

Comment: For *anoy* two groups $G$ and $H$, there is always a homomorphism from $G$ to $H$: $g\mapsto e_H$.

Comment: How does this relate to algebraic topology?

Comment: I think OP wants to know if there's a way to extend 3 morphisms between $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ into a commutative square

Answer (score 2):

Obviously there's a trivial homomorphism $g\mapsto 1$ between any two groups.

However even if we assume that there are non-trivial homomorphisms $A\to B$, $B\to D$ and $A\to C$ this does not imply the existence of a non-trivial homomorphism $C\to D$. Even when they are injective.

Take $C$ to be any non-abelian simple group, e.g. $C=A_n$ is [the alternating group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_group) for $n\geq 5$. Now fix non-trivial $g\in A_n$ and let $A=\langle g\rangle$. Finally let $A=B=D$. With that setup let $A\to B$ and $B\to D$ be identities, while $A\to C$ the inclusion. These are all non-trivial and injective.

But there is no non-trivial homomorphism $C\to D$. Indeed, since $D$ is abelian while $C$ is not, then such homomorphism has to have a non-trivial kernel. Since $C$ is simple then the kernel has to be whole $C$, hence the homomorphism is trivial.